# Google Data Studio: sorting stacked bar chart

Tags: looker-studio

I have the following stacked bar chart created in Google Data Studio:

[image]

I would like to sort it so that "0" values at the bottom and "5" values are at the top.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by setting the **Secondary Sort** of the [Bar Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560):

- ***Field***: `Field` (Ensure that it's the same field as the Breakdown Dimension)
- ***Order***: Ascending
- ***Aggregation***: Average

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4a55cb50-2c1c-4caa-a2b3-f892c0b9e4d3) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]